# Reordering similar elements together within an array

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays, java

I have a requirement where I need to group similar elements together within an original list.

For example:

I/P array:

`[1, 2, 3, A1, B1, 4, B2, 5, 6, C1, B3, B4, 7, 8, 9, 10, A2, A3, 11, 12, A4, C2, D1]`

Now I would like to group the elements starting with an alphabet such that all the elements belonging to a specific alphabet are together and would be placed right after the first occurrence of that alphabet.

O/P array:

`[1, 2, 3, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, 4, 5, 6, C1, C2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, D1]`

One trivial solution that I came up with is to maintain a HashMap denoting the alphabets and its elements, `Map<Character, Queue<Element>>` and do the following steps:

1. Iterate through the list and if an alphabet is encountered, do one of the following:

   1.1 If the alphabet doesn't exist in the map, add it to the map with an empty queue, `map.put('A', new LinkedList<>())`

   1.2 If it exists in the map, then remove it from the original list and add it to its corresponding queue in the map, `list.remove(element)` and `map.get('A').add(element)`
2. Iterate through the original list again and when an alphabet is encountered, add its corresponding queue from the map right after it.

I think this solution would work but I am not sure if it might fail for an edge case or if it is an optimal one(even though its complexity is O(n)).

Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: Why not just sort the list?

Comment: "Better" by what criteria?  What metric are you trying to optimize?  You certainly can't do any faster than $O(n)$ running time: it takes that long even just to read the entire input.